# Is there a way to make SOAP actions optional in a SOAP 1.1 Java implementation?

Tags: java, web-services, soap

We currently have a whole suite of SOAP 1.1 service implementations that do not care if a SOAP action is provided.  They will gladly take an empty SOAP action and they still work fine, somehow linking the call to the correct method.

We also have a new SOAP 1.1 service implementation that absolutely will not function without a SOAP action.

The problem is, most of the clients are lazy and do not provide SOAP actions, and while I'd like to ask them to do so, it's not currently feasible.

I cannot for the life of me determine what configuration item is allowing the existing services to allow empty SOAP actions.  Does anyone know how to disable SOAP action validation on SOAP 1.1 services?

Our container implementation is WAS 8.5.5.13 and we're running Java 1.8, in case that's important.

Thanks,
Peter

Comment: Hi Risser The SOAP action can be empty maybe the older implementations are adjusting the header i.e. headers.addHeader("SOAPAction", endpoint); Could you add something similar to the new implementation ?

Comment: No, the only SOAP action reference in the code (by doing a search for "soapaction") are two references in client WSDLs to other services.  There's nothing setting a SOAP action in the provider, as far as I can tell.  I mean, it seems like there must be something somewhere, but nothing like what you're describing.  Thanks though!

Answer (score 0):

You can use  [this](https://github.com/reficio/soap-ws) Java library that enables handling SOAP on a purely XML level.

Supports the following:

1. Supports WSDL 1.1
2. **Supports SOAP 1.1 and 1.2**
3. Supports all four WS flavors: rpc-encoded, rpc-literal, document-literal and  document-encoded
4. Supports SSL and basic-authentication
5. Supports SOCKS, HTTP and HTTPS proxies
6. Supports SpringFramework
7. Supports JUnit, Spock and Arquillian

> Then, you can send a SOAP envelope (as a String) invoking the post() method:

```
 client.post(soapAction, envelope);
```

> You can also **skip** the SOAPAction header and send the envelope only:

```
 client.post(envelope);
```

Otherwise, the default implementation forces `SOAPAction` field.

From `SOAP 1.1` [documentation](https://www.w3.org/TR/2000/NOTE-SOAP-20000508/):

> The SOAPAction HTTP request header field can be used to indicate the intent of the SOAP HTTP request. The
>   value is a URI identifying the intent. SOAP places no restrictions on
>   the format or specificity of the URI or that it is resolvable. An HTTP
>   client **MUST** use this header field when issuing a SOAP HTTP Request.
>
> soapaction    = "SOAPAction" ":" [ <"> URI-reference <"> ]
>   URI-reference =
>
> The presence and content of the SOAPAction header field can be used by
>   servers such as firewalls to appropriately filter SOAP request
>   messages in HTTP. The header field value of empty string ("") means
>   that the intent of the SOAP message is provided by the HTTP
>   Request-URI. No value means that there is no indication of the intent
>   of the message.

Examples:

```
SOAPAction: "http://electrocommerce.org/abc#MyMessage"
SOAPAction: "myapp.sdl"
SOAPAction: ""
SOAPAction:
```

Comment: Except, I'm not the client, I'm the provider.  I don't have any control over what the clients do.  And, I agree with you as far as SOAP action being required for SOAP 1.1, except... all my 1.1 implementations are functioning just fine without it. I have no idea why.  If anyone knew why, that would probably answer my question.  Thanks though!